# Python match element in list to strings in list and create dict with multiple values

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of sample names and a list of file names containing the sample name:

```
sample_names = ['SampleA', 'SampleB', 'SampleC']
```

```
file_names = ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', 
              '/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']
```

I would like to match the sample name to all file names and create a dictionary with multiple key values as in `dictionary` below. Any suggestions?

```
dictionary = {'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv',
                          '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv',
                          '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv'],
              'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv',
                          '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv',
                          '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv'],
              'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv',
                          '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv',
                          '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}
```

Comment: Why is `file_names` a nested list?  There's only one sublist, so it might as well be a regular list...

Comment: Why this question gets so many upvotes is beyond me. `{'SampleA': '/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv',
    '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv'}` isn't even a valid dict. Please clarify your question by fixing the expected output.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I was overthinking a `for loop` to generate the `file_names` list, updated above. @blhsing, good catch, updated `dictionary` above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected result is ambiguous.  You call it dictionary but it's actually a list of invalid dictionaries. You can either obtain a list of single-key dictionaries or an actual dictionaries with one key per sample name.  In both cases the values of the keys need to be lists or tuples in order for them to contain multiple file names:

For a single dictionary:  (which makes the most sense)

```
result = { sn:[fn for gr in file_names for fn in gr if sn in fn] 
           for sn in sample_names}

print(result) # single dictionary

{'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', 
             '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv', 
             '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv'],
 'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', 
             '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv', 
             '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv'], 
 'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv', 
             '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv', 
             '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}
```

For a list of single-key dictionaries:

```
result = [ {sn:[fn for gr in file_names for fn in gr if sn in fn]} 
           for sn in sample_names ]

print(result) # list of single-key dictionaries

[{'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv', 
              '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv']},
 {'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', 
              '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv',
              '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv']},
 {'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv', 
              '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv', 
              '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}]
```

**[EDIT] New answer based on revised question:**

Your self-answered post works the same way as this (without the list nesting) but, if you have a large number of sample names and/or file names, this may take more time than necessary.

You can improve performance by going through the list of files only once and using a regular expression to identify the sample name key:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

pattern = re.compile("|".join(sample_names))
result  = defaultdict(list)
for fn in file_names:
    for key in re.findall(pattern,fn):
        result[key].append(fn)
        
print(result)

{'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv',
             '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv',
             '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv'],
 'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv',
             '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv',
             '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv'],
 'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv',
             '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv',
             '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}
```

*Using regular expressions will give you better control on pattern matching (e.g. if you need the sample name to be last and followed by a specific extension)*

Comment: I didn't see this answer until after posting my recent updates to my post. I have corrected the invalid dict and posted an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# output dict
dictionary = {}
# temp list to keep matched paths
temp = []
# iterate over sample_names, file_names(2d) lists
for sample_name in sample_names:
    for file_name in file_names:
        for f in file_name:
            # if a sample_name matches path
            if sample_name in f:
                temp.append(f)
    # save dictonary for sample_name
    dictionary[sample_name] = temp
    # clear temp list
    temp = []
print(dictionary)
# {'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv'], 'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv'], 'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you're trying to do is not possible. A dictionary can have 1 key and 1 value. So it's basically a 1-1 relationship. However, the value can be a **list**. So it can be something like this:

```
dictionary = [{'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv']}, {'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv','/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv']}, {'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}]
```

To achieve this, the following code can be used:

```
sample_names = ['SampleA', 'SampleB', 'SampleC']
file_names = [['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv'], ['/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv','/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv','/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv'], ['/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv','/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv','/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']]
f_lst = []
for name in sample_names:
    dictionary = {}
    dictionary[name] = []
    for each_list in file_names:
        for inner_file in each_list:
            if inner_file.split(".")[0][-1] == name[-1]:
                dictionary[name].append(inner_file)
    f_lst.append(dictionary)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
[{'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv']}, {'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv']}, {'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}]
```

Comment: Your `dictionary=` is surrounded by square brackets so its a list. Why include the square brackets?

Comment: @moken my bad. It's just a dictionary. You can just access the dictionary by
f_lst[0]

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this with:

```
dictionary = {k:[v for v in file_names if k in v] for k in sample_names}
print(dictionary)
```

`{'SampleA': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleA.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleA.tsv'], 'SampleB': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleB.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleB.tsv'], 'SampleC': ['/path/to/group1/bin_1/group_1_bin_1_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_2/group_1_bin_2_SampleC.tsv', '/path/to/group1/bin_3/group_1_bin_3_SampleC.tsv']}`